# Very strange behaviour of parseInt and map

Tags: javascript

Take a look at this experiment conducted on jsconsole.com

```
> parseInt("00")
0
> ["00"].map(parseInt)
Array (1)[ 0 ]
> ["123", "00"].map(parseInt)
Array (2)[ 123,NaN ]
> ["00", "123"].map(parseInt)
Array (2)[ 0,NaN ]
```

I've stumbled upon this by trying to do some date-time parsing. The problem seemed to be the fact that I didn't specify which integer base I want. Using `parseInt(x, 10)` solves my problem but could someone explain to me how `["00"].map(parseInt)` and `["123", "00"].map(parseInt)` could possibly differ for the value of `"00"`? I might be missing something extremely obvious here, but if I'm not this would mean that there's something wrong with `Array.prototype.map` or `parseInt` or both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect that. Thanks and sry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the extra parameters `map` adds to the method call.  Try the following snippet to get the correct results.  This prevents `parseInt` from receiving them.

```js
console.log(["123", "00"].map(it=>parseInt(it)))
```